# how to autocomplete file name like this in zsh

Tags: autocomplete, zsh

I have a file: Oasis - Sitting Here In Silence.mp3

I wanna type "here<tab>" then autocomplete

like file search

how to do that?

thanks a lot

Comment: Some other options: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259511

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are looking for is Zsh Tab completion but you have to surround "here" with asterisks

```
> *here*   <then press Tab>
```

Here is an excellent article on how to search, use tab completion, and wildcards.
[Getting started with Zsh](https://opensource.com/article/19/9/getting-started-zsh#:%7E:text=Search%20with%20Zsh,current%20or%20any%20other%20subdirectory.)